# ionic app deployed on server keeps refreshing

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an ionic app, when deployed on server refreshes every 5 seconds, but in local everything is fine.
Why is this happening?

Comment: I can't say will it work on not without testing. try this command `ionic serve --no-open`

Comment: It doesn't happen in local that I try command. It happens only on PWA version. @debugger

Comment: how exactly are you deploying?

Comment: Could be the auth issue (oauth silent refresh) perhaps?

Comment: Can you explain more please? @BoradAkash